# Meta tags for different languages

Tags: html, metadata

I'm making a multi-language website and I'm sure that I saw a while ago that there is a meta tag to tell search engines the URL of the same page in a different language.

I'm currently using the language tag below, but is there another tag to list the same pages URL in different languages?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
```

Something like??

```
<meta http-equiv="alternative-language" content="es" ref="/es/page.php">
```

Comment: Just a heads-up for you - http-equiv="content-language" is planned to become invalid in HTML5, which recommends using the "lang" attribute instead. (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-content-language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used it, but in theory:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="/es/page.php" hreflang="es" type="text/html">
```

Comment: It's `alternate`, not `alternative`.