# How to detect if a website has been translated into other languages?

Tags: web, translation

I am trying to determine if a given website has been translated into any other languages programatically.

I've tried making get requests using a variety of combinations such as es.domain.com, domain.es, domain.com/es, and domain.com.es. I am then making another request for sites that return a 200 to try to weed out false positives (website renders the English language page, etc.). For these requests I'm using a phony url (xyz123.domain.com, domain.xyz123, domain.com/xzy123) and making sure that the status code is not 200 and the body is not empty. I'm still getting some false positives though, for example www.domain.com is owned by one company whereas www.domain.es is owned by someone else. So while I'm getting a successful response for www.domain.es, it is not actually their website.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to check this?

Thanks!

Comment: There really is no standard for this.  Unless a website includes links to translated versions in their content or meta-data, anything else is basically a guess.  Guesses will result in false positives and false negatives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948465/meta-tags-for-different-languages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying sub domains is not a valid way to detect if a website is translated.

There is no standard to signify a website has been translated, therefore any programmatic function would not be accurate.

Until a standard is implemented, your best option is a brute force method, like the one you are doing, and physically verifying the site yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's sort of what I figured. We've found some decent success by scanning the homepage for links to different language versions (Espanol, Francais, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna be your best bet. Scan lang tags etc...hopefully they will bring this into standardization one day.